# RxJS: combine multiple map operators

Tags: rxjs

I want to have two maps inside one pipe, like this:

```
take(1),
map(({ users } => users.filter(user => user.uid = uid)),
map((data: User) => {
   let user = Object.assign({}, data)

   if ('_seconds' in user.createdAt) {
      user.createdAt = new Date(user.createdAt._seconds * 1000)
   }

   return user
})
```

I never have experience with RxJs before, but I guess, this looks so wrong. What the proper way to do this?

Comment: What's the *problem* with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with it. However, I don't see why you need to have multiple `map` operator. You can merge them like this:

```js
take(1),
map(({ users }) => {
   const data = users.filter(user => user.uid = uid); // something should be wrong here, data is an array.
   let user = Object.assign({}, data)

   if ('_seconds' in user.createdAt) {
      user.createdAt = new Date(user.createdAt._seconds * 1000)
   }

   return user
})
```